# Bootstrap 3 + Chosen + jquery validate loses format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I have the code below 
http://jsfiddle.net/emamut/CBjmj/4/

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
$('form').validate({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

but when select validate the formatting is lost and returns the normal format of Chosen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `errorPlacement` option, when you use `insertAfter` it inserts the error message between the `select` element and the `div.chosen-container`. This fouls up the CSS used for the chosen widget. For example, if you use `insertBefore`, the problem goes away:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
    $('form').validate({
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else if (element.is('select')) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        } else
        {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to add the error message bellow the chosen, you always can add it after adding this clause to the errorPlacement:

```
else if (element.is('select')) {
   error.insertAfter(element.siblings(".chosen-container"));
}
```

I've forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alfupe/0Lwgmmav/