# jquery validation with custom style <select>

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I made registration with the help jqueryValidation. Everything would be fine, but I noticed, that "select" from bootstrap looks ugly in Opera and Mozilla Firefox. I used [jquery-chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)  to resolve my problem, but these two scripts don't want to work together. The border don't change color, and the error message will not show. Any help please? Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">     
     <select name="country" id="country" data-placeholder="YOUR COUNTRY*" class="chosen-select"  tabindex="2">                
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                ...
                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
     </select>                
</div>
```

MyValidation js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#contact-form').validate({
        rules: {         
          country:{
            required: true
          }
        },       

    highlight: function(element) {          
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');              
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {            
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');              
    }
      });
});
```

and custom dropdown js:

```
<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select' : {}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jquery chosen plugin hides the select element, and builds its custom html to imitate it.

At that jquery validation plugin ignores hidden elements by default and doesn't validate them

You can set `ignore` property for the validator when initializing and force it to not ignore anything:

```
$('#contact-form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    //your other validation settings
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood. It helped. But message error print not under field, how usually, it print over the field. Don't understand why, and how it to fix..and border color does not change to red when an error

Comment: @T_E_M_A, you'll have to refer to the jQuery Validate documentation and read about the `errorPlacement` callback function.  Use this option to precisely place the error label.

Comment: @Sparky, before I added the script for dropdownlist, everything worked as it should. This script somehow changed the location of the output error...Maybe it needs to be fixed?

Comment: @T_E_M_A, the plugin, by default, places the error label after the `select` element.  As explained by paulitto's answer above, Chosen hides the actual `select` and creates it's own dropdown list which the validate plugin knows nothing about.  Validate is still correctly placing the error message after the `select` element, but since it's hidden, it appears to be out of place.  That's why you'll have to adjust it by using the `errorPlacement` option.

Comment: @T_E_M_A, See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24834289/594235